# Template override when complex conditions are met

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have some XML which is semantically similar to the below:

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <a>
      <b t="0"/>
    </a>
    <a>
      <b t="0"/>
    </a>
    <a so="2">
      <b t="1">
        <c n="x"/>
      </b>
    </a>    
    <a>
      <b t="2">
        <c n="x"/>
      </b>
    </a>
    <a>
      <b t="1">
        <c n="y"/>
      </b>
    </a>
    <a so="3">
      <b t="2">
        <c n="z"/>
      </b>
   </a>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <a so="1">
      <b t="2">
        <c n="x"/>
      </b>
    </a>
    <a so="4">
      <b t="1">
        <c n="z"/>
      </b>
    </a>
  </parent>
</root>
```

And I have a template which applies to all `a` elements:

```
<xsl:template match="a" mode="whatever">
  do some nice stuff with the content of a
</xsl:template>
```

I have some templates that override the behaviour to do nothing at all if certain conditions are met.
e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="a[@t='0'][preceding-sibling:a[@t='0']" mode="whatever">
<!-- ignore this node entirely -->
</xsl:template>
```

(N.B. in the above example the document order matters, in the question below it does not)

Which works great, however now I need to do something rather more complex.
I want to ignore the 4th `a` element in the above example xml, given that the following conditions are met:

- `b/@t="2"`
- there is some other `a` within the same parent element, where `b/@t="1"`
- the `b/c/@n` values are the same for both `a` elements.

In the example xml the last node should not be matched by this rule since the values of @n are different.

I don't care which order the `a` nodes are in, or if there is other stuff in between. However I can state that the nodes will be in the order shown, with no intermediate nodes, if required.

There is probably some other way to achieve this other than with template overriding, however for code neatness I'm really looking for a template-based solution, if one exists.

I am currently using xmlstarlet, which does not support XSLT2.0 or XPATH2.0, I can investigate other engines, but would prefer to stick with what I have if at all possible.

N.B. Node in different `parent` nodes should not affect eachother - e.g. the node marked with `@so=1` should not be affected by the presence of node marked with `@so=2` as they are in different parent nodes.
Likewise for `@so=3` and `@so=4`. In the example none of these nodes should be matched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XSLT snippet removes the 4th `a` as requested:

```
<!-- all a keyed by the value of b/@t -->
<xsl:key name="k1" match="//parent/a" use="b/@t"/>

<xsl:template match="//parent/a[b/@t = 2 and
                     key('k1', 1)/b/c/@n = b/c/@n]"/>
```

The match clause selects all `a` having `b/@t = 2`. Then it checks if there is an `a` where `b/@t = 1` having the same value for `b/c/@n` as the current element.

If the checking should only happen within the same parent, you can add the ID of the parent to the key like this:

```
<!-- all a keyed by parent node and the value of b/@t -->
<xsl:key name="k1" match="//parent/a" use="concat(generate-id(..),'|',b/@t)"/>

<xsl:template match="//parent/a[b/@t = 2 and
                     key('k1', concat(generate-id(..),'|',1))/b/c/@n = b/c/@n]"/>
```

The latter XSLT script transforms the following XML:

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <a>       <b t="0"/></a>
    <a>       <b t="0"/></a>
    <a so="2"><b t="1"><c n="x"/></b></a>
    <a>       <b t="2"><c n="x"/></b></a>
    <a>       <b t="1"><c n="y"/></b></a>
    <a so="3"><b t="2"><c n="z"/></b></a>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <a so="1"><b t="2"><c n="x"/></b></a>
    <a so="4"><b t="1"><c n="z"/></b></a>
  </parent>
</root>
```

into

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <a>       <b t="0"/></a>
    <a>       <b t="0"/></a>
    <a so="2"><b t="1"><c n="x"/></b></a>

    <a>       <b t="1"><c n="y"/></b></a>
    <a so="3"><b t="2"><c n="z"/></b></a>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <a so="1"><b t="2"><c n="x"/></b></a>
    <a so="4"><b t="1"><c n="z"/></b></a>
  </parent>
</root>
```

Comment: Last time I tried to use key I got a headache! I then forgot it even existed.

Comment: Does this account for different `context` elements? There should be no cross checking between them

Comment: @DJL: so when adding a second context element containing `<a><b t="2"><c n="y"/></b></a>` it should be left intact? No, this will be deleted. Could you please update the question to clarify? Maybe add a second context element?

Comment: I thought this covered it "within the same context element". I will edit to clarify

Comment: @DJL Yes, you're correct. I overlooked this when reading the question. But still, maybe you can just update your sample XML with the one from my updated answer. If it's correct, that is.

Comment: I'll check your updated answer now to see if it works.

Comment: Yes, I got it working, once I figured out that the `1` in your `concat(generate-id(..),'|',1))` is the value of the @t attribute on the node we are matching against, not some magic value